# Google Sheets lookup with contains condition

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In the monthly statement of my bank account I want to tag every transfer with a category:

| Description | Amount | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emma's veggie shop visa#1022 | 45 | groceries |
| Zettle payment Bert automobile | 345 | car |
| Hugo discount visa#1023 | 99 | groceries |
| Gpay: Emma's veggie shop | 39 | groceries |

I made a table with all the keywords and corresponding tags:

| Key | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| Emma's | groceries |
| Bert automobile | car |
| Hugo | groceries |

Now I need a formula to fill out the Tag-column in the first table automatically, a bit like
`=ylookup(A2,Table2!A1:B3,2)` where A2 is mapped to a row in Table2 that **contains** it's key word (not like vlookup **matches**) and returns the corresponding tag.

I'd use `=vlookup()`, but the transfer descriptions don't always begin the the same string. I've also looked at arrayformula, but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: @BlindSpots `Table2!A1:B3` is a valid range reference in Google Sheets.

Comment: is `Table2` a sheet name or named range?

Comment: Table1 & Table2 are sheets, yes. Should have called them sheet1 & sheet2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter()` and `search()`, like this:

```
=single( iferror( filter(Table2!B$2:B, len(Table2!B$2:B), search(Table2!A$2:A, D2)) ) )
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304).

The `single()` function is one of the many undocumented functions in Google Sheets. It returns the first element of a 1D or 2D array.